# Parse YahooWeather JSON response

Tags: java, android, json, yahoo-weather-api

I try to make a simple weather app and for that I use YahooWeather api. So I get a response something like this:

```
/**/yqlCallback({
    "query": {
        "count": 3,
        "results": {
            "channel": [{
                "item": {
                    "pubDate": "Fri, 16 Jan 2015 11:00 am EET",
                    "condition": {
                        "temp": "1",
                        "text": "Cloudy"
                    },
                }
            },
            {
                "item": {
                    "title": "1",

                }
            },
            {
                "item": {
                    "title": "2",

                }

            }]
        }
    }
});
```

The only data's I need from here is pubDate, temp and text. So here is how I try to get those values.

```
    JSONObject main = json.getJSONObject("query").getJSONObject("result").getJSONArray("channel")
    .getJSONObject(0);
    JSONObject details = main.getJSONObject("condition");
String t1 = details.getString("text");
String t2 = details.getString("temp");
String t3 = main.getString("pubDate");
```

This give's me this error: One or more fields not found in the JSON data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In current json no `JSONObject` present with `result` key. Use `results` instead of `result` to get `JSONObejct` from `query` JSONObject:

```
JSONObject main = json.getJSONObject("query").
                getJSONObject("results").getJSONArray("channel");
JSONObject items = main.getJSONObject("item");
JSONObject details = items.getJSONObject("condition");
String t1 = details.getString("text");
String t2 = details.getString("temp");
```

Comment: @WdarinS: see my edit answer `condition` object is in `item` jsonObject so you first need to get `item` object from main then get `condition` from it

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I needed to add at the end of `.getJSONArray("channel").getJSONObject(0).getJsSONObject("item");`
anyway, thanks.